# How to convert this jquery code into a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery

Newbie here...

I have this amazing popup code that I found here. I'm using it in my projects just fine. What I'm asking is, can someone help me convert it to a plugin -ish code so that I can target required divs and use it easily on more than one element.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offsetY = window.pageYOffset,
    $body = $('body'),
    $win = $(window),
    $close = $('.mobile-filters-close'),
    $open = $('.filters-toggle'),
    $holder = $('.mobile-filters-wrapper'),
    $stuff = $('.mobile-filters-wrapper .filters');

    // Close with 'esc' key
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) $close.trigger('click');
    });

    $open.click(function () {
        offsetY = window.pageYOffset;
        // Block scrolling
        $body.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'color': '#FFFF00',
        'backgroundColor': '#00D',
        'top': -offsetY + 'px'
    });

    // Show popup
    $holder.css('display', 'block');
    });

    $close.click(function () {
        // Allow scrolling again
        $body.css({
        'position': 'static',
        'color': '',
        'backgroundColor': ''
    });

    /**
    * Remove the following scrollTop()'s if you want.
    * just a UI tweak that the user would expect.
    **/
    // Make the page stay at the position it was at before the overlay
    $win.scrollTop(offsetY);
    // Reset the overlay scroll position to the top
    $stuff.scrollTop(0);
    // Hide popup
    $holder.css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

And this is what I'm looking for:

```
$('.popup').CoolName({
    // options
    $close = $('.mobile-filters-close'),
    $open = $('.filters-toggle'),
    $holder = $('.mobile-filters-wrapper'),
    $stuff = $('.mobile-filters-wrapper .filters');
});
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Try that yourself. the internet is yours. Then ask if you are in problem while doing.

Comment: And if @EvanTrimboli's link is too complex, https://www.freelancer.com/.

Comment: I'm more designer than coder. No intentions of learning much more than I should. Anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned things up for you a bit:

```
// Plugin function
function coolName(triggers) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var offsetY = window.pageYOffset;

        // Close with 'esc' key
        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) triggers.close.trigger('click');
        });

        triggers.body.click(function () {
            offsetY = window.pageYOffset;
            // Block scrolling
            triggers.body.css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'color': '#FFFF00',
                'backgroundColor': '#00D',
                'top': -offsetY + 'px'
            })
        });

        // Show popup
        triggers.holder.show();

        triggers.close.click(function () {
            // Allow scrolling again
            triggers.body.css({
                'position': 'static',
                'color': '',
                'backgroundColor': ''
            })
        });

        /**
        * Remove the following scrollTop()'s if you want.
        * just a UI tweak that the user would expect.
        **/
        // Make the page stay at the position it was at before the overlay
        triggers.win.scrollTop(offsetY);
        // Reset the overlay scroll position to the top
        triggers.stuff.scrollTop(0);
        // Hide popup
        triggers.holder.hide()
    });
}

// Implementation
coolName({
    close: $('.mobile-filters-close'),
    open: $('.filters-toggle'),
    holder: $('.mobile-filters-wrapper'),
    stuff: $('.mobile-filters-wrapper .filters')
})
```

Note that when making a plugin there's always the potential for variable names, function names, and HTML element names to interrupt with the other person's code. I would prefix all of your variables/functions with "coolName_" to prevent this, if that makes sense.

Comment: It actually worked with some minor problems like missing ; or 2 but couldn't managed to use it with 2 different triggers. Also, although this version looks identical to my version, it didn't restore scroll position correctly. But I'm continue to work on this version too

Comment: I do this kind of UI stuff all the time, you can email me `ethancrist96@gmail.com` and I'd be willing to screenshare you for more help. What you're trying to accomplish can actually be done in a more elegant/simple way, I'm just not sure what specifics you want. I'd love to help you out.